# How session management can be achieved after OAuth2 authentication?

Tags: java, session, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

In my application after authenticating user using OAuth2 framework, I want to maintain session until user logs out? What would be the best possible approach?

Comment: You gave too little info. Please describe what you want to achieve and your architecture in more detail and what specific problems you want to solve.

Comment: also: authentication with OAuth 2.0 in itself is not possible